# Downgrade from server to desktop - is it possible?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

I inherited a Windows Server v2008 computer, which, from my very limited experience (I am not a server expert, in any way, shape or form!!!) is very basically structured. There are quite a number of problems with this machine, including failed Hard Disks (no longer detected by the OpSys). I believe it was meant to be a fileserver though I know for a fact that only one person accessed it from the server itself (accessing like a desktop).

My question is - is it possible to downgrade from this Server platform back to a PC desktop machine?

If so, what would I have to do to do so?

My preference would be to use either Win7 professional or Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure; just install Desktop version of Windows; just replace the hdd

Comment: Thank you, Ramhound - I was worried that I would have to do tricky things like backup/restore/save and move stuff around.      So, do I treat it like a simple installation of an OpSys, like on any other PC? Good to know... has been a bit of a worry!!!

Comment: There is no way to downgrade. You can erase your current operating system, and install another if you have one; backup your data first. Windows is pretty much Windows; don't let the word "server" scare you off. Windows Server 2008 is the server counterpart of Windows Vista.

Comment: @Megastar the backup/restore procedure you only need if you wanna keep/move some of the files especially Personal Data (Word Documents Excel Sheets e.g) from the old OS to the New

Comment: Thanks, konqui = already backed up my data to my NAS and to the cloud (DropBox & Box). I'm only worried if I had to do stuff to the OpSys before I installed the Win7 component. From what I can gather, as long as my personal data is "safe" I can do what I want with the OpSys!!!! Thank you, everybody!!!!

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing special about windows server **operating systems**. You can simply remove the broken disk, insert an new disk and install a regular OS on it.

Two things which are good to know though:

1. Server **hardware** is usually not build to boot fast or to be silent. Powering up a server might result in a jet-engine howl of fans and nothing on a screen for a few minutes. This is fine. Servers are not intended to be rebooted often and this is not a problem for server usage. It makes for less than perfect desktops though.
2. Server hardware might be extremely fast for some parts (e.g. very good NICs. On-board SAS2 RAID etc etc), and very slow for other parts (an graphics card is likely on-board but it is unlikely to be suited for gaming or for multiple monitors).

Having written all that. Have fun. Enjoy your new hardware.

Comment: Thank you, Hennes - happily, it is a PC base boosted to Server capabilities. I was (am) hoping to end up with a really powerful PC!!!! Fingers crossed!!! Megastar

Comment: It is interesting to see how often people expect servers to be fast. (Granted, they often are).  But there are plenty exceptions. E.g. a simple domain controller might run on the slowest sever CPU available (and use less power, generate less heat. Cheaper) because it does not need to calculate fast. It does have to have low latency though.  Still, finger crossed, you might have a fun toy to play/work with. :)

Comment: Hi Hennes - I know it is a fast machine- I've seen it in action. It's just that I don't know how to "run" a server. Now it is "mine", I need to be able to use it, and not just watch it run as a server!!!!!! <grin>